# Tracing function calls in javascript (facebook)

Tags: javascript, facebook, function

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension that could be used to auto reply on a Facebook chat. My idea is to override the receive and send(ajax) functions and to act on their call. But I'm having problems. I can't find out which functions are used to send nor to receive chat messages. I tried to trace Ajax calls but I just can't find my way around their scrambled and overly complicated JavaScript files (which btw have very strange names).

So can you please suggest me way of tracing the function calls? I can't rally find my way around debugging and really don't know where to start with break points.

Comment: What about using Firebug(in Firefox) or Developer Tools (in Chrome)?

Comment: I tried, but I can't find my way around them. I tried tracing the line where the function is called that requires the Xhttp request but no luck there.

Comment: Use the chrome's Breakpoints. You just need to click on the line in your script on the left side of the text to get a breakpoint. Then when your code it called it automatically breaks. You should use "stepinto". The button is on the right side. To bring up the debugger, press CTRL + Shift + J (goto the scripts tab and choose your script page)

Answer (score 3):

> So can you please suggest me way of tracing the function calls? I
>   can't rally find my way around debugging, and really don't know where
>   to start with break points.

Its really easy to [debug and trace javascript in google chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-exceptions.html). A quick [google search](http://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1AVSX_enIN437IN437&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=debug%20and%20trace%20javascript%20in%20google%20chrome) will tell you more. Just press `CTRL + SHIFT + J` to get the developer options in google chrome. Then goto your call and do a `stepinto` or `stepover` functions. You can use the `stack trace` option to help you. I have attached a pic for an idea.

[image: Google Chrome Debugger]

The same can be achieved in firefox by using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/logging)

**EDIT**

> I tried, but I can't find my way around them. I tried tracing the line
>   where the function is called that requires the Xhttp request but no
>   luck there.

Inorder to trace AJAX calls you need to add breakpoints in your `callback` functions; The call back function will get the breakpoint triggered when they are called.

Comment: Well i tried all this but the problem is that facebook has optimized it's js files. So in 1 line, when you make it readable you actualy get  800+ lines of code.

Comment: Well i tried all this but the problem is that facebook has optimized it's js files. So in 1 line, when you make it readable you actualy get  800+ lines of code.
So here's what i done and what i've got:
First i found the request and clicked on the source link:
[link](http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/12255500/12255558_08b8_625x625.jpg)
than i found that it is happening at the 23d line:
[link](http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/12255500/12255611_ed0c_625x625.jpg)
this is what i've got(when made more readable):
[link](http://pastebin.com/gcMdHSak)